# Spring AOP adviced methods do not work. My configuration seems ok

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I'm trying to create a demo AOP application but it just does not work right.
I read through all tutorials and got it working with `@RestController` but as I tried it with a plain java spring driven application I just can't get it to work. Please review my files and tell me where my mistake lies in.

**Application Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.xetra.experimental")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AoptryoutnowebApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AoptryoutnowebApplication.class, args);
    DefaultClassToAspectImpl defaultClassToAspectImpl = new DefaultClassToAspectImpl();
    defaultClassToAspectImpl.doStuff();
  }
}
```

**ClassToAspect Interface**

```
public interface ClassToAspect {
  void doStuff();
}
```

**ClassToAspect Implementation**

```
@Component
public class DefaultClassToAspectImpl implements ClassToAspect {
  @FooAnnotation
  public void doStuff(){
    System.out.println("DoStuff!");
  }
}
```

**Annotation for Pointcut**

```
public @interface FooAnnotation {
}
```

**Aspect Class**

```
@Aspect
public class FooAspect {

  @Pointcut("@annotation(FooAnnotation)")
  public void methods(){
  }

  @Before("methods()")
  public void doAspect(){
    System.out.println("FooAspect before");
  }
}
```

Comment: Spring AOP only works for spring beans. You are creating a new instance outside the scope of spring, hence no aop.

Comment: you mean because I did not autowire DefaultClassToAspectImpl ?

Comment: No because you are doing `new DefaultClassToAspectImpl()` instead of obtaining the instance from the container.

Comment: Well Im used to Spring applications which are fully configured already. Can you kinda show me how I can get this Instance from a container? Just a short snippet would be nice!

Comment: `SpringApplication.run(AoptryoutnowebApplication.class, args).getBean(ClassToAspect.class). doStuff();` should do the trick.

Comment: that solved the issue - thank you. You can create an answer out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using a non Spring managed instance by doing `new DefaultClassToAspectImpl()`. Spring AOP only works for Spring managed beans, because by default Spring AOP is proxy based.

So instead of doing `new DefaultClassToAspectImpl()` you should be obtaining the instance from the `ApplicationContext`. When using Spring Boot the [`SpringApplication.run`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#run-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String...-) call returns an [`ApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html). Here you can use one of the `getBean` methods to obtain the instance you want.

```
ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(AoptryoutnowebApplication.class, args);
ClassToAspect bean = getBean(ClassToAspect.class);
bean.doStuff();
```

This way you get the Spring managed

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. replace `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = false)`
2. change pointcut to 
   `@Pointcut("execution (* your.package..*.*(..)) && @annotation(fooAnnotation))")`